# How can I use 'rented' fonts from Skyfonts on Latex

Tags: luatex

I have a subscription from Skyfonts and I am disappointed that LualaTex is not able to use fonts "rented" from Skyfonts. Other applications, Word, etc. are able to use these rented fonts.

Is there a known fix? Thank you

> Skyfonts is a font subscription service that allows one to access a huge library of otherwise expensive fonts for a very nominal monthly fee. However, the fonts are not stored as files in the font directory (Windows) but in some encrypted form. Can fontspec be modified to access these fonts? I can share my Skyfont subscription details for anybody who can test and help find a fix.

Comment: You might want to explain skyfonts to us. At a glance they seem to store the fonts in a non-standard way (are they *ever* on your PC in a standard font format?) which means that they've made it deliberately difficult for you to use them except in applications they've designed for.  I feel this is more a question for skyfonts (but that doesn't mean I think it's off-topic here)

Comment: You might want to try first with xelatex which uses the fc-cache utility to find fonts, if that can find them but luatex can't some adjustments to luaotfload might be possible

Comment: Look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303162/29873