# Using Adobe Fonts with (Xe/Lua)Latex

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, adobe

## Motivation

Although Adobe Fonts is proprietary software (and that's probably the whole issue here...), I think it's also really tempting to use some of the Adobe Typefaces (e.g. Minion Pro, Arno Pro, etc.) in a professional LaTeX document without having to buy each individual typeface (especially if you're already subscribed to Adobe's Creative Cloud).

## Issue

Because of the way Adobe integrates its fonts into the system, it's absolutely seamless to use new fonts in MS Word or any other application. However, I've been unable to get Lua- or XeLaTeX to recognize any of the fonts using `fontspec`.

### Edit

Reviewing this question it felt to me I forgot to clarify what Adobe Fonts *is*. Basically it's a font subscription service which comes "free" with a Creative Cloud subscription (Again, which makes it tempting to use..). Key issue is, you don't get any *.ttf or *.oft files (as far as I can find) instead you "rent" these fonts and they are (magically?) usable in most desktop applications. Sadly, apparently not by `fontspec`.

## Solution?

I did some research and found that the .otf files should be stored in a hidden (windows) folder. However, on my system, there are only cryptic files:

```
PS C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CoreSync\plugins\livetype\r> dir


    Verzeichnis: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CoreSync\plugins\livetype\r


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        05.06.2021     21:30         214072 14596
-a----        05.06.2021     21:30         255088 14597
-a----        05.06.2021     21:30         213764 14598
-a----        05.06.2021     21:30         255808 14599
-a----        05.06.2021     21:30         216440 17968
-a----        05.06.2021     21:30         256712 17969
-a----        05.06.2021     21:30         257084 17970
```

So my question is: Has anyone succeeded using Adobe Fonts with LaTeX? Or has anyone any additional leads on what to try?

Kind regards!

Comment: Are you trying to use SkyFonts? If so, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276541

Comment: SkyFonts is a different service, I believe, however the issue seems to be the same. Adobe Fonts also "rents" its typefaces..  However this issue seems to be 5 years old, maybe there are some new solutions?

Comment: This answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500730/202780 might be useful in that they suggest loading the font by PostScript name rather than display name.

Comment: Yes, I've tried using the PostScript name, sadly to no avail..

Comment: You can rename the fonts and put them somewhere your TeX system finds them.

Answer (score 2):

You probably installed it to a hidden directory in your own user account, instead of for all users (which requires administrator privileges).  On Windows, LaTeX or XeTeX can find a font file located in any of the following places:

- A system font directory
- The local TeX tree (`kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` on TeX Live)
- Your user TeX tree (`kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME` on TeX Live)
- The current working directory, if you are compiling from a project folder
- A directory that you set the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable to
- In MikTeX, a TeX tree you create in the MikTeX console
- A directory that you specify with the `Path=` font loading option of `fontspec` commands, such as saving them to a `fonts` subdirectory and loading them with something like `\setmainfont[Path=fonts/, Extension=.otf]`.

On Linux, LuaTeX and XeTeX can also read user font directories, such as `~/.fonts/`.

Pragmatically, what you probably want to do is remove the copies you installed to your user account and reinstall the font for all users.  If you are sure you only want a font for TeX, and don’t want to clutter your font-selection menus, you can save them to a subdirectory of your `TEXMFLOCAl` tree instead. To make absolutely sure you are using the correct version of a font and archiving it with the source, save a copy to a subdirectory of your project folder. You can then optionally re-run `fc-cache -f -s -v` and `luaotfload-tool -f -u -p -v`.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue on macOS and found a solution in [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258711/were-does-adobe-fonts-aka-typkekit-aka-creative-cloud-fonts-store-fonts-on-my). As you mentioned in the last part of your question, the fonts are installed in a hidden folder and have somewhat cryptic names. On macOS, their location is `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CoreSync/plugins/livetype/.r` while on Windows it's `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CoreSync\plugins\livetype\r` (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65205516/3330422) on SO).

Once in this folder, as you have noticed, the OTF files have numbers for names instead of the font name as usual. However, you can find the number–name correspondence in the file `../.c/entitlements.xml` on macOS or `../c/entitlements.xml` (the `.c` or `c` folder is at the same level as the `.r` or `r` folder above).

With this information one could manually copy the OTF files to a different location and rename them but fortunately someone has written a Bash script to automate the process, as mentioned in [another answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65602505/3330422). You can find the Adobe Fonts Revealer script [here](https://github.com/Kalaschnik/adobe-fonts-revealer), together with instructions for installing and running it on macOS or Windows.

I tried the Adobe Fonts Revealer on my macOS Ventura 13.1 system and it worked flawlessly. It copied the OTF files to `/Users/<username>/Downloads/FONTS` and renamed them in the process. Following this, I was able to use these fonts with LuaLaTeX by specifying the `Path` option in `fontspec` as suggested by @Davislor:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path=/Users/<username>/Downloads/FONTS/, Extension=.otf]{MinionPro-Regular}
```